# Sending notification one device to another device

Tags: android, notifications

I have an apps in Android and I need code for sending notification one device to another device, that notification is also store into the database.

Thanks

Comment: look for google cloud messaging

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send a "notification" from one device to another. Notifications occur on only one device.

You can send messages (like "SMS" or "push notifications") from one device to another. Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is convenient for Android to Android messaging. To other devices, you might have to get more complicated, use a service (like parse.com) or even build your own XMPP server.